# Renting a flat in Montenegro

Tags: accommodation, rental, summer, montenegro

I want to rent a flat in Montenegro for 2 persons for about one month. Is there any problem I should be aware of (I heard in some countries you need to have a job or local bank account to rent a flat).

Comment: I suspect that the job/bank-account requirements would never apply to a short-term rental.  Montenegro has a strong tourist sector, so one-month rentals are surely common there.  Unfortunately, I cannot help further as my closest experiences are in Croatia, not Montenegro, so probably similar, but not directly applicable.

Answer (score 2):

[Borrowing from one of my answers on a similar question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/44963/how-to-rent-a-flat-in-france-for-about-a-month/44972#44972):

> Long-term rentals everywhere around the world typically require the tenant to prove the ability to pay the current and every future month rent. This is done by showing salary slips (usually the last 3 in France), payment receipts from previous rental agreements, a reference letter, and/or binding someone else to be your guarantor to cover any missed payments (this person too will have to show proofs).

Short-term rentals on the other hand are often bound by simpler contracts (if any) which involve up-front payment for either the full rental period, or blocks of several consecutive months. No need to ask for proof of payment ability if the tenant pays everything in advance.

Now I don't know about Montenegro specifically. Going out on a purely speculative limb though I would say that since [Airbnb does have various short-term rental listings for Kotor, montenegro](https://www.airbnb.com/s/Kotor--Montenegro?checkin=06%2F01%2F2015&checkout=07%2F31%2F2015&room_types[]=Entire%20home%2Fapt&ss_id=8059ny1v), it should be easy to rent a flat in Montenegro for a short period of time without having to worry about proof of employment and other bureaucracy.

For completeness sake note that a gazillion other rental websites exist out there. Here on TSE we don't really do recommendations, hence the answer to `what would be a good site for renting a flat in Montenegro (in the bay of Kotor)?` might be off-topic here.

Comment: It's not really true that everywhere in the world you need to prove that you are able to pay your rent. By now, I only had to prove it in England, and I also lived in Poland, Spain and Germany (several flats in each).

Comment: @simpleBob In Poland, Spain and Germany nobody asked you for employment proof/history?

Comment: yes, I think in those countries, most people just assume that if you couldn't pay it, you would not be asking to rent it. Which, somehow, makes sense.

Comment: @Daniel not really, you could end up staying months with the landlord getting no income because you can't afford. Unless it's very easy to evict a tenant in those countries