# How can I stay in the center of Paris cheaper than AirBnB?

Tags: budget, accommodation, paris

I am considering staying in Paris for a relatively long period (10 to 12 weeks) next year.

Since hotels are expensive, I usually use AirBnB, but even AirBnB costs about €45 per night, which is still quite expensive.

I believe there should be some cheaper alternatives, like renting a room, since AirBnB is targeted for travellers staying for a few days to a few weeks, so if you keep staying for a few months, it would not be comparatively cheap enough any more.

So, is it possible to rent a room in Paris as a traveler (i.e. no valid visa), for only 10 to 12 weeks? Otherwise, what kind of options are available to stay in the center of Paris, possibly for less than or equal to €35?

By "the center of Paris", I consider 1st, 2nd, 7th, and 8th arrondissements. And I only consider any accommodations I have my own room in.

Comment: What options are there for this in *any* other Western capital? There's no free lunch - if someone could make more money by renting out their place on Airbnb they would do so a long time ago.

Comment: (45€ is cheap in Paris ... ) Have you looked for "Private Rooms"  on AirBnb Type services ?

Comment: It's your call and shouldn't make much of a difference to the question but I think the 3rd, 4th, 5th and 6th arrondissement ought to be considered part of the centre. Even parts of the 9th are very central, certainly as much as the 7th or 8th.

Comment: @Max According to [numbeo](https://www.numbeo.com/cost-of-living/in/Paris) the "Apartment (1 bedroom) in City Centre" costs €1,063 (€35/day), so €45 is more than average. What do you mean by "AirBnB Type" services?

Comment: @Blaszard Those figures are for yearly rentals, which are usually much cheaper than short-term ones.

Comment: @jpatokal Right, so the price of 3 months rent should be somethere between the yearly rent and AirBnB. And it is 1 bedroom but I'm totally fine with studio.

Comment: Related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/44963/how-to-rent-a-flat-in-france-for-about-a-month/44972

Comment: @jpatokal Or in the case of Japan there is a "weekly-mansion", which costs more than the yearly rent but definitely cheaper than using AirBnB. I'm looking for such services, if that is available.

Comment: @Blaszard I mean short term rental services, AirBnb, VRBO, HomeAway ... and probably a few French specific ones  (which I do not know)

Comment: Become friends with a local and stay with him/her.

Comment: Looking for apartments in Paris on AirBnb for two random three-month-long periods shows that there are entire apartments available in the center for less than €1050 per month (ok, there are taxes and fee on top of that, but even then there are still apartments left for less than €35 per night). So maybe you're just out of luck for the dates you're interested in? Or did you first look at shorter rentals? Note that many hosts (or Airbnb?) give discounts for people staying several weeks/months.

Comment: Wait, why has this question got closed off? There are many such questions already posted here, not only accommodations but also transport, to ask for a cheaper alternative. The price and availability of the alternative  acommodations won’t fluctuate, which should make this question outside of the scope of the shopping question.

Comment: @martin.koeberl I also checked it again but they are in outskirts (17th, 18th, etc...). One room is at 9th and looks pretty good, but it is likely that the host has not used AirBnB for a while and just keeps opening the reservation.

Answer (score 2):

Dorm beds go for about 15 euros per night.

Homestays, and airbnbs, start at around 1000 per month, though some are available for a bit less (750+).

So, unless you want to sleep under a bridge, it's fair to say that, yes, you can get accommodation for less than 45 euros per night. But under about 30 euros per night, it becomes rather difficult, unless you are willing to compromise.